# Spatial Analysis with Repeated Measures

Tags: anova, spatial, spatio-temporal

I am doing an agricultural study in which I analyzed parameters of fruit and treated them with different conditions. The fruits were measured once a week for four weeks. Now, I would like to know if the plot of land (i.e. the spatial location) has an influence on my dependent variable.

Which model would I best use for this analysis?